# Как поместить WebView в фрагмент?

Tags: android-fragment, activity, java, android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как поместить во фрагмент WebView, например, при нажатии на кнопку, у меня открывается фрагмент и тут же должен открываться WebView.

```
  public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle               savedInstanceState) {

    WebView webView = (WebView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.webView_frag1);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);
    }
}
```

Но, к сожалению, программа выдает ошибку!

Comment: В данном случае надо бы логи из LogCata прилагать. Там бы вы увидели (скорее всего), что приложение падает на строчке 

    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

по NullPointerException, что показало бы, что предыдущая строчка не находит WebView в разметке активити.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, понял, буду смотреть в случае чего туда!

Comment: @Verteletsky, такие мелочи в разработке, порой, жутко раздражают)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Скорее всего у вас нет объявления WebView в лэйауте активити и приложение падает при попытке совершить действие над объектом

> webView

коий, на момент обращения **=null**

Если я правильно понял (*а я экстрасенс*), то WebView элемент у вас в разметке фрагмента... Если так, то надо сначала в методе onCreateView() загрузить разметку, а уж потом в ней поискать WebView и что-то в него загрузить.

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle               savedInstanceState) {

//Загружаем разметку из XML
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false);

//Находим WebView и загружаем что-нибудь
WebView webView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView_frag1);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

//Метод должен возвращать View
return v;
}
}
```

Comment: @Verteletsky, пожалуйста) Немного опыта и тоже станете мысли читать)))

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, А вот собственно логи, http://joxi.ru/52ae4MQs4GzL20 , правда, приложение работает, но файл index.html не открывается =(

Comment: @Verteletsky, ну, попробуйте какой-нить сайт загрузить (прописав в манифесте разрешение на интернет). Если загрузится - проблема в HTML-ке.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, понял, сейчас попробую.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, изменил на адрес, переходит, все работает, значит проблема в самом html файле, но что не так, не понятно, вот содержимое файла

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
       asdasdasd
    </body>
    </html>

Comment: @Verteletsky, ну, значит грузити из assets как-то не правильно. Попробуйте как файл из памяти телефона загрузить.